# What is the difference between RunWithElevatedPriviledges and HostingEnvironment.Impersonate()?

Tags: runwithelevatedprivileges, hosting-environment

What is the difference between RunWithElevatedPriviledges and HostingEnvironment.Impersonate()?

Both are used to run code with higher priviledges..

Comment: interesting question. As far as I know, HostingEnvironment.Impersonate should be an old asp related implementation, while RunWithElevatedPrivileges is SharePoint specific... but maybe someone else can provide a more in depth analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Impersonate` is the ASP.NET equivalent to `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges`.

`SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` cannot work in ASP.NET context as it calls for SharePoint APIs.

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/8da8192b-fcb3-444c-846f-251d6aaa96ea/whats-the-difference-between-hostinghostingenvironmentimpersonate-and)

I have an asp.net web app that must execute code under the context of the current user (via identity impersonate, as it needs to call out to various resources). There are some blocks of code, such as writing exceptions to the event log that must run as the app pool account.

In SharePoint, (which has asp.net set up very similar to my web app), there is SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges. This ensure a block of code runs as the app pool account. The equivalent in asp.net is as follows:-

```
using (System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Impersonate()) 
{ 
}
```

[Source](http://rnowik.com/Quicknote-Equivalent-to-SPSecurity-RunWithElevatedPrivileges-in-standard-asp-net-4-0.aspx)

Comment: OK, speaking strictly from the sharepoint point of view, lets say we have sharepoint site. Then, does it matter which technique we use?

Comment: Yes, it matters a lot, the wrong technique might give you a  solution to your requirement but it might create a overhead. Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Impersonate will be used in the ASP.Net object model.

Comment: i want to know as which user it gets impersonated? current loggedin windows  user?